# Not updated arguments (arguments.callee.caller.arguements)

Tags: javascript, arguments

reference fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kLpygs6e/1/

While Executing this code block, I need to get updated arguments object in functions _wait and _inner

```
function main(string1 , number1){
   string1 = "STRING 1"; // changing argument with name string 1
   arguments[1] = 1000000; // changing argument using its index 2
   console.log("main >>> " ,JSON.stringify(arguments));
   // now calling _wait method
   _wait("WAIT STRING");
}

function _wait(str){
    // picking arguments from arguments.callee.caller.arguments
    var _args = arguments.callee.caller.arguments;
    console.log("_wait >>> " ,JSON.stringify(_args));
    // callin one more inner function
    _inner();
}
function _inner(){
    // picking arguments from arguments.callee.caller.arguments.callee.caller.arguments
    var _args = arguments.callee.caller.arguments.callee.caller.arguments;
    console.log("_inner >>> " ,JSON.stringify(_args));
}
main("welcome", 578);
```

Output :

```
main >>>  {"0":"STRING 1","1":1000000}
_wait >>>  {"0":"welcome","1":578}
_inner >>>  {"0":"welcome","1":578}
```

Can anyone solve this problem ?
I were not able to pass the own arguments of main method to any other methods.

Comment: Updating `arguments` by assigning to parameter variables, `arguments.callee`, `callee.caller` and `caller.arguments` are **all** deprecated. Stop using them immediately! Start to `"use strict"` mode!

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you were trying to solve with this mess?

Comment: What is the expected output? What is `callObj`?

Comment: @Bergi I need to use this, although it is deprecated. I have been using this for past 6 years. Now the recent updates of all browsers seems to be producing wrong outputs. Update arguments in the scope must be retained all over when we use "caller.arguments".

Comment: You still didn't tell us why you'd need this - probably you don't and there are much better solutions. That the code is old or was working 6 years ago doesn't mean it was a good practice or not deprecated.

Comment: @Bergi the method _wait will contain a wait condition method. after that wait to particular condition i need to callback the origin function which called _wait with one particular argument updated, so that it seems to be very simplified flow. Now If the arguments have not been updated then every _wait must sent with details of all arguments and callback method

Comment: Yes, you really should pass a callback to `_wait` for that, which takes the updated argument. You don't need to mangle the other arguments, they should be accessible by closure to the callback. Why do you want to avoid the callback? Probably there's an even better way to solve your problem which doesn't include a "wait" function at all.